# How to get Authorization code from identity server without login form

Tags: .net, angular, identityserver4, openid-connect

I need to implement AUthorization grant flow with identity server.
The basic requirement is 
1. Connect with identity server with client_id and get Authorization code
2. Using Authorizarion code & clientId, get access token.
All this has to be done without username & password .

So currently when I am calling the API i.e. /authorize with below params:

```
var settings = {
    authority: `https://${url}`,
    client_id: clientId,
    audience: clientId,
    redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/callback',
    automaticSilentRenew: true,
    silent_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/assets/silent-refresh.html',
    response_type: 'code',
    scope: 'openid ${scope}',
    loadUserInfo: true,
    // response_mode: "query",
    allowPlainTextPkce:true
};
```

I am getting redirected to the login form. Is there any way by which I can directly get the code without login credentials

Comment: How is the user authenticated in this scenario? The `prompt` parameter for the authorize endpoint allows you to control this behavior but you can only use `prompt=none` if they already have a session. That code looks like it related to oidc-client-js which I think has a signInSilent function that will do a `prompt=none` call automatically.

Comment: Is this a user authentication or is your application trying to authenticate itself to the IdentityServer?

Comment: @mackie: Yes it is related to oidc-client-js. As per the documentation which I read 
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/authorization-code-grant , we can get the authorization code just by passing above params and it will authenticate itself to identity server .

Comment: @Randy Yes our application trying to authenticate itself to identity server . We dnt need user authentication

Comment: The auth code or hybrid flow requires an authenticated user session (i.e. a cookie on the IDP side) to work. The normal way for machine to machine stuff to work is using client credentials and the token endpoint but since this is a public client (i.e. is client side) there's no way to do this securely. Sorry.